# Why error: Redefinition; previous definition of y0 was ‘function’?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The only thing written in the code are:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int x0, y0;
```

And it’s giving me an error when I compile: ‘y0’: redefinition; previous definition was ‘function’

Comment: Please write the main function

Comment: Yes, I saved and then compiled and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/y0.html perhaps

Comment: @ArchitGoyal currently the main function is empty, nothing is written in there.

Comment: write an empty main function and it will work

Comment: Get rid of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: which compiler, which flags are you using?

Comment: I ran the same code in gcc and got "|undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|" and "||error: ld returned 1 exit status|"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `y0` is a built-in function in gcc (and maybe some other compilers), see:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

And then scan through for:

> Outside strict ISO C mode (-ansi, -std=c90, -std=c99 or -std=c11), the functions ... **y0** ... may be handled as built-in functions...

So, **tl;dr**, use a different name.

You can see the helpful error message that gcc generates [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YmtE2SL3AgcQBHs9), although, in gcc 8.1 at least, this is only a warning:

> prog.cc:4:9: warning: built-in function 'y0' declared as non-function [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
>    int x0, y0;

So, for next time OP, so that you won't get voted down (although I didn't - this time), please:

- include the full text of the error message in your question (I mean really, why not?)
- tell us which compiler you are using (make and version)

Thanks.

Comment: Adding `-std=c++??` also removes the builtin.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okey doke, didn't see that in the docs anywhere (but then again, I didn't look very hard).  You'd _think_ that gcc would infer this from compiling a .cc / .cpp file but evidently not.